# Not able to determine how a UI app automatically starts after a reboot

Tags: windows, windows-10, ssd, autostart

I have a Windows 10 computer that was originally upgraded from a Windows 7.  About a year ago I got a Samsung External SSD drive and installed its accompanying software.  Whenever I attached the SSD harddrive, I would get a prompt asking for my password.  Everything worked fine.   However a month or 2 ago after the latest Windows 10 patch, I would get a prompt for password whenever I rebooted and logged in and not wait for me to attache the SSD harddrive.

I am trying to figure out how this is possible.  I can always rename the executable to prevent the popup, but I want to know how this executable is being initiated.  Knowing this would also ensure other programs are not being started without my knowledge.  I have checked my startup tag, searched registry settings and reviewed the Task scheduler, without success.  Is there any place else to check?

Also, I think when I installed the latest patch, I clicked on the option to auto login to complete the installation.

Thanks,

I figured out how this was happening.  Windows 10 "shut down" is different than the past.  Now when you "shut down", any program that is currently running automatically starts next time you reboot.  To prevent this from occurring you have to do a force shutdown.  One way is using this command:  Shutdown –s –f.

Comment: This is not a duplicate.  In my post I said, " I have checked my startup tag, searched registry settings and reviewed the Task scheduler, without success".

Comment: I figured out how this was happening.  Windows 10 "shut down" is different than the past.  Now when you "shut down", any program that is currently running automatically starts next time you reboot.  To prevent this from occurring you have to do a force shutdown.  One way is using this command:  Shutdown –s –f.

Answer (score 2):

If you've checked the registry and the Startup files, the program in question could have been set up as a service.

Click on the Start Button and type in services.msc

This will bring up a new program that you can search through and see if it's starting from there.